# Is there a function in ghostscript or similar tools to differentiate between CMYK and RGB pages in PDF?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I know the  ghostscript sDEVICE=inkcov  function which shows all colored pages. Unfortunately I can not differentiate in RGB and CMYK.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ghostscript, no.

You are aware that PDF allows for much more than RGB or CMYK colour spaces ?

There's also DeviceGray, which along with DeviceRGB and DeviceCMYK completes the 'Device' space.

There are four kinds of CIE spaces, L*a*b, CalGray, CalRGB and ICC.

Then there are Separation, DeviceN and NChannel spaces. While these have Device space alternates, would you consider the space to be RGB or CMYK or something else ?

Also, consider the example of a page where all the marking elements are in RGB, but there is a transparency group, and the group blending space is CMYK. Is that an RGB page or a CMYK page ?

Note that any page in PDF can have any combination of colour space. So pages need not simply be RGB or CMYK.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you. I am interested  primary in getting information about the preprint capability of a pdf. So I would like to know if there are pages without DeviceGray or DeviceCMKY. Is there a way for doing that?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is still 'no'. It would be possible to write a Ghostscript device which could give you that information, but there is nothign currently in existence which will do so. Its possible the Acrobat Preflight tool can give you this, I'm not certain.